# On beam suspended by wires

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, equilibrium, statics

My question involves sample problem 9-8 of the book "Physics" by Halliday, Resnick and Krane, 5th edition. So I could understand the answer given but there is something that is not explicitly explained that I'm having some trouble understanding or at least I don't think it was clearly explained.
But first some background, the first thing to do is to setup our coordinate system and then choose the axis to apply the torque conditions and account for all the forces acting, that is our Free body diagram.
After applying the equations then we would end with something like this. [image]

$\Sigma F_x=F_h-T_h$
$\Sigma F_y=F_v+T_v-Mg-mg$

$\Sigma \tau=-F_v cos(\theta)+F_h(Lsin(\theta))+mg(\frac{1}{2}Lcos(\theta))$

We cannot solve this system of equations because we have more variables than equations, however the book says that a fourth relationships comes from the fact that the tensions $T_h$ and $T_v$ must add to a resultant Tension directed along the wire. So now here is my question. Why is this true?  Why does the resultant tension is in direction in the wire and not facing some other side probably a bit sideways to the direction of the wire? The book tries to supply an explanation but it just left me with more doubts.
Ad verbum

> A fourth relationship comes from the requirement that $T_v$ and $T_h$ must add to give a resultant tension $\vec{T}$ directed along the wire. The wire cannot support a force component perpendicular to its long direction.(This is not true for its rigid beam).

What does that second sentence even mean? and how does it relate to the fact that the direction of the tension vector is directed along the wire?. I drew the second statement, but I didn't gain any insight from drawing a picture or maybe I'm understanding incorrectly.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explain this to yourself by gripping a string or very thin wire in your left hand—so it's completely clamped, unable to translate or rotate—and then pinching the other end with two fingers on your right hand and moving that hand in various directions.

Unless you're pulling directly away from your left hand—**if the pulling force has any [component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Decomposition_or_resolution) in any lateral direction (meaning any direction perpendicular to the wire length)**—the wire will unstably bend and/or buckle **without limit**. Try it. (Compare with a stiff rod or beam, which you can stably push laterally if you're gripping one end, i.e., if the rod or beam is [cantilevered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantilever).)

In other words, when a structure has no bending stiffness, unless the end loads point directly away from each other, the structure will bend and/or buckle. Put another way, a string/cable/wire can stably accommodate only axial tension. That's the meaning of that statement from the book.

Comment: So for tension to exist in a string it is necessary for a force to be pulling away from the cable, that is, the line of force is in the string/cable ,and on its abscense the cable will bend or curve. But what did the author mean by saying "The wire cannot support a force component perpendicular to its long dimension"? Btw thank you for your answer.

Comment: I made some edits and added some links to clarify. If confusion remains, please specify which word or phrase in that sentence is causing trouble.

Comment: Assuming we have a cable that makes an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal like in the first picture, then it could be resolved in its components. However I don’t see how they would be perpendicular to the wire. Would a drawing be too much to ask?

Comment: Just rotate your $T_h$ and $T_v$ counterclockwise by $\theta$ (and recalculate them, of course) so that one component is along the wire and the other is perpendicular to it. Rename them $T_\mathrm{axial} $ and $T_\mathrm{lateral}$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: So if I understood correctly the cable will withstand the highest tension in its Axial direction, whereas a lateral force (maybe that same tension) applied perpendicular to the the cable would either buckle it or even break it(?). Thanks a lot.

Comment: It will allow tension in the axial direction only. Try the experiment! The wire won't break, it'll just bend without limit. Play with a string to understand the behavior!